# Is OnBufferingUpdate event called every second while playing?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am currently writing an app for Android, including a media player. As I want to show the user the current state of the player, I want to keep the time currently played and the buffering progress updated.

After implementing the interface `MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdate`, I realized, that this one is called every second, even after the buffering has finished. It then reports a percentage of `100` every second.

My question now:

Is this behavior specified somewhere? Can I safely use the `MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdate` event to update my playing-time, or should I implement a timer my own to keep that one updated? Is there another event I can use, that's called every second while playing (not triggered on `PAUSE` or after `FINISH`)?

I found that question here, LINK - [Android: onBufferingUpdate() not called after reaching 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069783/android-onbufferingupdate-not-called-after-reaching-100) - where @ThaMe90 points to the documentation - but I don't get what should be the "bug" here ...

Comment: Ok, I at least now know, that it's not called when it's a local resource (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526601/onbufferingupdate-not-being-called-in-mediaplayer) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, due to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html#onBufferingUpdate(android.media.MediaPlayer,%20int)), this method is **"called to update status in buffering"**, so when you reach 100%, buffering status shouldn't updated anymore (it makes sense, am I right?).

Unfortunately, there is a disease, which consumes process of developing software for Android platform - OEMs modify this platform due to their needs. I am pretty sure it's one of those examples.

I've test is this method called on different devices and here is the result of my observation:

- onBufferingUpdate method **is called after reaching 100%** on all of Samsung devices **(heavy modified OS)**
- onBufferingUpdate method **isn't called anymore after reaching 100%** on all of Moto G, which **has slightly modified Android**

Well, it looks like a bug, which became a feature on Samsung devices ;)

[image: It's not a bug, it's a feature]